# Sort by custom field is not working

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

I have a custom query:

```
<?php
query_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'properties',
'meta_key' => 'pd_city',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
));
?>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. The posts on this page should be listed alphabetically by city (Burnaby, New Westminster, Richmond, Surrey), but they are listed in a random order (I'm not sure how they are being ordered).

Not sure what I'm missing. I created the 'properties' post_type via the 'Post Meta' Wordpress plugin if that makes a difference.

http://www.professionalrentals.ca/new-properties-test-page/

---

Attempt using WP_Query - Also **DOES NOT WORK**

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'properties',
    'meta_key' => 'pd_city',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: I think I have told you this previously, but if not, here I go: **NEVER EVER** use `query_posts`. It messes up the main query, is slow, breaks page functionality, breaks pagination, and reruns queries. It is just plain evil. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query, or use `WP_Query` or `get_posts` to construct custom queries for secondary queries

Comment: I tried both of those things already, and it gives me the same result. I actually went back to my other post and looked at all the suggestions and tried them before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Piter is right, don't use `query_posts`.

You could do something like:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'properties',
    'meta_key' => 'pd_city',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Just make sure you have the values right for your `post_type` and `meta_key` params.  I.e, I use an underscore for all my meta keys: `_properties`.

I have a nearly identical query running on a client's project here: http://centerpoint.com/properties/?pgd=1&v=list&filter=1&list_type=all&sortby=city

Comment: I've edited my post above to include the code using WP_Query, but it is giving me the same output as query_posts. I'm not sure if you're familiar with the "Post Meta" plugin, but I have a section with a meta_key = properties_1, and in this section I have my city with a meta_key = pd_city. Now could this nested meta_key thing be the reason I am having issues?

Comment: Do you have access to the database?  If you do, it might be better to pull up a property post type in the `wp_postmeta` table and see what meta_keys are stored with it.

Comment: I do have access. I can find pd_city 4 times in the 'meta_key' column (for the 4 test properties I have added). Not sure what that means though...

Comment: If each of those properties has `pd_city` as a meta key with a city name as a value, the query should work.

Using your code above, debug your query by `print_r($the_query)` to see what query WP is building.  That may help determine where the error is.

Comment: Is there something in specific I'm looking for? This spits out a whole wack of stuff...

Comment: One of the things it spits out is the actual MySQL query that WP creates when querying the database.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at the Post Meta plugin you are using, and it appears to save it's meta values as serialized arrays. Therefore your query is never going to work - WP doesn't know how to order a bunch of serialized arrays.

If you really want to use a plug-in (rather than build your own meta fields), I'd recommend you dump Post Meta and switch to [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). Note you'll need to deactivate Post Meta for ACF to work.

Comment: Is there a way I can do a nested query or something? Like query one meta key, to get info, and then query the next meta key inside that? I'm too many hours into this project to scrap it and start over.

Comment: There's no way to do this with nested queries. You could just select everything that uses the pd_city meta key, then order them in PHP. But this would be complicated. I still recommend switching plugins. It would just mean re-adding the cities.

Comment: Incidentally, after I pointed out this flaw in Post Meta, the plugin author responded "Our next version is coming soon and this version will have the wordpress default meta function."

Comment: He said he was releasing a new version 'soon' about 6 months ago as well. Hmmmm... I wonder if I can convince my client to have it sorted by date for now until this new version is out. Cause I'm banging my head against the wall looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have a really ridiculous work around that ends up running the query multiple times (I'm sure I'll get torn apart in the comments for this), but it works for now so here goes.

This only works if you know exactly which fields you will be sorting between. AKA I have a list of cities I need ordered alphabetically. And I know there are only these cities.
*(I guess you could run a separate query to get this array from the DB but I didn't want MORE queries)*

```
<?php
$listOfCities = array('burnaby', 'delta', 'ladner', 'new westminster', 'north vancouver', 'richmond', 'tsawwassen', 'vancouver', 'white rock');

foreach ($listOfCities as $cities) {

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'properties',
'meta_key' => 'pd_city',
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'pd_city',
            'value' => $cities,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )),
'order' => 'ASC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($the_query->have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

    echo get_field(pd_city);

endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();

}
?>
```

And after all that the client wanted it ordered a different way, but since it processes it based on what's first in the array to last, I just changed the array to:

```
$listOfCities = array('vancouver', 'richmond', 'burnaby', 'new westminster', 'north vancouver', 'white rock', 'delta', 'ladner', 'tsawwassen');
```